# ¿Como mostrar correctamente un servicio web en un sitio sin dar su código fuente?

Tags: nodejs, webservice, mongodb

Ofrezco un servicio gratuito pero no quiero entregar su código fuente. Es decir, si el usuario **Juan** obtuvo el servicio puede mostrarlo en su sitio, por ejemplo: http://serv.juanpage.com/ o http://juanpage.com/serv/ o como el usuario quiera... En fin, lo que quisiera es que al entrar al sitio muestre el sitio mio con el servicio, por ejemplo http://servicioprestadodemisitio.com?usuariousandoservicioID=ABCDEFG. Es decir que cuando entren al sitio de Juan muestre mi sitio completo como un iframe. **¿Cual es la manera más optima para hacerlo sin entregarle el código fuente?** ya que con el código fuente puede alterarlo y puede hacer más cosas que no estoy ofreciendo gratuitamente :) el servicio que ofrezco en un simple chat hecho con NodeJS y MongoDb.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que la idea del iframe no es buena. Lo que puedes hacer es tener una especie de **"compilador"** que coja tu código, y genere un proyecto que tenga los mismos archivos, pero los archivos javascript los creen con código ofuscado. Puedes usar una librería como  esta: https://www.npmjs.com/package/javascript-obfuscator

Answer (score 0):

Aquí hay dos opciones:

=> Una de ellas es que creés el **iframe** pero "minimices" el código e incluso lo hagas indescifrable para que tus clientes les sea imposible y tedioso el querer modificarlo. Esto último lo puedes lograr con herramientas como [javascript-minifier](https://javascript-minifier.com/) y [javascript Obfuscator](https://www.danstools.com/javascript-obfuscate/), Obviamente debes guardar un respaldo para ti, pero la versión "comprimida" será la que le muestres y le des a tus clientes mediante el **iframe**, y Sinceramente no es necesario comprimir el código HTML, no se puede hacer mucho con eso, ya que lo que te preocupa es que lleguen a modificar tu código javascript.

=> La Segunda Opción es que ejecutes todo el código importante en el lado del servidor y solo le muestres al usuario los **"resultados"** para que el servicio pueda funcionar correctamente. Supongo que es un **servidor VPS** ya que solo ahí se pueden ejecutar aplicaciones NodeJS, así que no será problema que instales el paquete [Socket.IO](https://socket.io/) `npm install socket.io`. Por si no lo conoces, este paquete permite realizar una interacción entre el cliente y el servidor, ejecutando comándos del lado del servidor para finalmente poder hacer cosas como **mostrar resultados**, dejando todo el código importante en el lado del servidor donde nadie más pueda verlo más que tu.